# Python Setuptools Distribute: Optimize Option in setup.py?

Tags: python, optimization, software-distribution

Is there a way to set the optimization level from the setuptools `setup.py` file? Is there *any* way to set the optimization level within setuptools?

I've got lots of `__debug__` style logging that isn't needed on release.

Comment: Use the `logging` module, together with a configurable log level and `.debug(message)`, instead of `__debug__`-guarded sections for logging.

Comment: What about asserts? How can they be disabled for an optimized/production run?

Answer (score 0):

You control the use of .pyc vs .pyo with the -O switch on the Python command line.  Python won't even attempt to use .pyo files without the -O switch, so compiling your .py files to .pyo files at setup time won't help: you need to invoke your program with the -O switch, or the PYTHONOPTIMIZE environment variable.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to control when one uses an egg file on OSX? Plus I am running using nosetests and not with python directly.